# Karate DSL: How to add specific key and value (XML) as x-www-form-urlencoded to body of request?

Tags: karate

I am trying to add a specific key, value to the body of a request via Karate as x-www-form-urlencoded

The last "And request" in the example fails.

Via Postman, I have created an working example which gives us the correct response. (exported the mainpart below)

```
"item": [
    {
        "name": "http://www.google.com/api",
        "request": {
            "method": "POST",
            "header": [
                {
                    "key": "Content-Type",
                    "name": "Content-Type",
                    "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "type": "text"
                }
            ],
            "body": {
                "mode": "urlencoded",
                "urlencoded": [
                    {
                        "key": "our_xml",
                        "value": "<create_stuff> .... XML .... </create_stuff>",
                        "type": "text"



Scenario: XXX

Given url 'http://www.google.com/api'

And header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

And request{"our_xml" : read('classpath:xml/post.xml')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed the existence of `form field`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#form-field - header will be set automatically.

```
* form field key = 'our_xml'
* form field value = read('classpath:xml/post.xml')
```